# Selecting all data from a table where it is the first of the month

Tags: sql, ibm-data-studio

I am using Data Studio to query a large table in a relational database. I am attempting to get all of the data where a certain column with the data type of DATE is the first of the month. The dates in the columns range from about 1990 to 2023 and are in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

I am not very proficient with SQL and all answers I've found for anything similar don't seem to make any sense to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM data_table
WHERE date_column ... is the first of the month;
```

Comment: please clarify what database you use

Comment: It is a relational database

Comment: OK.The let's go step-by-step. Is it DB2? Is it Informix?

Comment: It is DB2. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming DB2 because you've tagged IBM Data Studio:

Can you use `DAYOFMONTH()` like this?:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data_table
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(date_column) = 1;
```

Comment: This got the job done! All of the prior solutions I found that implemented the DAYOFMONTH() function where needlessly complicated and confusing or didn't work. This is simple and makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: What if there is not an entry as the first day of the month? E.g 7th and 10.

Comment: @VictorAxelsson That is a good point, to capture all non-end of month dates I used a bunch of AND's and OR's as such:
`SELECT * FROM data_table
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) = 30 
 AND MONTH(dt_col) != 4
 AND ((DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) = 30 
 AND MONTH(dt_col) != 6))
 AND ((DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) = 30 
 AND MONTH(dt_col) != 9))
 AND ((DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) = 30 
 AND MONTH(dt_col) != 11))
OR ((DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) = 28
 OR DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) = 29)
 AND MONTH(dt_col) != 2)
OR (DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) >= 1
 AND DAYOFMONTH(dt_col) < 28);`

Answer (score 0):

Using ORACLE SQL, I would employ the `to_char(...)` function:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table
WHERE to_char(date_column, 'DD') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Syntax to locate the First of the Month.  I use a CTE to populate a table with dates and then the actual query to pull only the dates where it is the First of the Month.

```
WITH fakeDates AS
(
    SELECT CAST('1/1/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/2/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/3/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/4/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/5/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/6/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/7/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/8/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/9/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/10/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/11/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/12/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/13/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/14/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/15/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/16/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/17/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2/01/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2/03/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/13/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('3/01/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('3/15/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('1/16/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('4/01/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('4/02/1998' AS DATETIME) AS DateField 
)

SELECT fd.DateField
FROM fakeDates fd
WHERE DAY(fd.DateField) = 1
```